# How can I reverse print the characters of a string in each cell using AWK?

Tags: string, awk, printing, field, reverse

```
Beth    45  4.00    0   0   .072
Danny   33  3.75    ^0  0   .089
```

The above is the file I want to operate.

I want to write an AWK script that can reverse print  the characters of a  string in every cell.

Here is the code:

```
BEGIN { OFS = "\t\t" } 
function reverse_print(str)
{
    s = ""; 
    N = length(str);
    for (i = 1; i <= N; i++)
        a[i] = substr(str, i, 1); 
    for (i = N; i >= 1; i--)
        s = s  a[i];
    return s;
}

{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
        $i = reverse_print($i) ; 
    print;
}

END {}
```

However, it does not work. The program somehow becomes dead.

I have found if I don't use the loop and handle each field one by one like the following,

```
BEGIN { OFS = "\t\t" }
function reverse_print(str)
{
    s = "";
    N = length(str);
    for (i = 1; i <= N; i++)
        a[i] = substr(str, i, 1);
    for (i = N; i >= 1; i--)
        s = s  a[i];
    return s;
}

{
    $1 = reverse_print($1) ; 
    $2 = reverse_print($2) ; 
    $3 = reverse_print($3) ; 
    $4 = reverse_print($4) ; 
    $5 = reverse_print($5) ; 
    $6 = reverse_print($6) ; 
    print;
}

END {}
```

it can work well.

Here is my desired output:

```
hteB        54      00.4        0       0       270.
ynnaD       33      57.3        0^      0       980.
```

I have thought hard but still cannot figure out where I did wrong using the loop.

Who can tell me why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the same variable `i` inside and outside of the function. Use a different variable in either location or change the function definition to `reverse_print(str, i)` to make the `i` used within the function local to that function rather than the same global variable being used in the calling code.

You should also make s and N function local:

```
function reverse_print(str,     i, s, N)
```

but in fact the code should be written as:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS = "\t\t" }
function reverse_print(fwd,     rev, i, n)
{
    n = length(fwd)
    for (i = n; i >= 1; i--)
        rev = rev substr(fwd, i, 1);
    return rev
}

{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
        $i = reverse_print($i)
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
hteB            54              00.4            0               0               270.
ynnaD           33              57.3            0^              0               980.
```

Comment: There is no need for using `n`, you can do directly `for(i=length(fwd), ...`

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.(This program is tested on GNU `awk` only and as per Ed sir's comment too this is undefined behavior for POSIX `awk`)

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS="\t\t"
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    num=split($i,array,"")
    for(j=num;j>0;j--){
      val=(j<num?val:"") array[j]
    }
    printf "%s%s",val,(i<NF?OFS:ORS)}
    val=""
}'  Input_file
```

Comment: You should mention that `split($i,array,"")` is undefined behavior per POSIX so it'll do different things in different awks. It's also a good idea to parenthesize ternary expressions as they will produce syntax errors in some contexts in some awks and parens help readability.

Comment: FWIW I'd write your ternaries as `val=(j<num?val:"") array[j]` and `printf "%s%s",val,(i<NF?OFS:ORS)` You actually don't even need that first one to be a ternary, just `val=val array[j]` will work on it's own. It's more robust coding to init your variables before you use them btw rather than after you've used them so `val=""` should come before the loop, not after it. Imagine the difference if 6 months from now you add code at the start of the program that uses a variable named `val` for some other purpose.

Comment: @EdMorton, sure Ed done the changes now, sorry didn't get your point for `val` variable so you want me to put the variable in starting itself of `awk` program.

Comment: What I'm saying wrt val is that you should init variables before you use them rather than after. For example, if you write `val=""; print val` inside a large work loop (as ask provides automatically) then you know when the print statement occurs that `val` has the value null. If instead you write `print val; val=null` then you're just hoping that some earlier code, maybe added a year after you wrote that print statement, won't change the value of `val` between it being set to "" and the print statement ocurring.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`rev` command in Linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rev.1.html): `rev - reverse lines characterwise`.

You can reverse a string by calling `rev` with awk builtin function [`system`](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/gawk_13.html#SEC98)   like:

```
#reverse-fields.awk
{
  for (i = 1; i <= NF; i = i + 1) {
    # command line
    cmd = "echo '" $i "' | rev"

    # read output into revfield
    cmd | getline revfield

    # remove leading new line
    a = gensub(/^[\n\r]+/, "", "1", revfield)

    # print reversed field
    printf("%s", a)

    # print tab
    if (i != NF) printf("\t")

    # close command
    close(cmd)
  }
  # print new line
  print ""
}
```

```sh
$ awk -f reverse-fields.awk emp.data
0    00.4    hteB
0    57.3     naD
01    00.4   yhtaK
02    00.5    kraM
22    05.5    yraM
81    52.4   eisuS
```

Comment: Code only answers are generally considered low quality. Could you add an explanation to your answer.

Comment: @LemonKazi sure. I was aware of that when I just paste the code from my gist for a quick answer. Thank you for remind me.

Comment: While it is nice to remind us of `rev`, your answer does not answer the question. Currently, you could just have done `rev file` which has the same effect as above.